# Not able to install the UiPath.Web.Activities.HttpClient package

Tags: uipath

I am unable to install `UiPath.Web.Activities.HttpClient` via the manage packages option in UI path studio.

Does the UiPath studio community version not allow to install this package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not able to search for `HttpClient` as it's just a lib of the package.

So simply search for "**web**" and under section "**official**" you should now be able to see your package:

[image: package list]

Install it and you have that lib available:

[image: installed package]